# SQL Server 2005 Order BY with an expression

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is there a possibility to order the result by an `ORDER` clause that contains an expression, something like

```
SELECT colX0 FROM tbp_name ORDER BY (colX1 IS NOT NULL)
```

or also a more complex expression ?

**UPDATE:**

In the meanwhile I have found a possibility to solve the above problem:

```
ORDER BY (case WHEN colX1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) ASC
```

however the question remains, if there is a possibility to order direct by an expression.

Comment: The reason your first attempt doesn't work is that SQL Server needs you to convert your boolean expression into a datatype that it can sort on. If you tried using that expression `colX1 IS NOT NULL` in a SELECT statement it wouldn't work either. As you've found in your second statement, you can ORDER BY an expression, so long as it's a valid one you could put in a SELECT statement.

Comment: @Rory: It was a bad example and this led me into a wrong direction (because it deals with booleans). Your comment should be the accepted answer, it answers my main question. I will accept the answer of gbn, because he shows why my example (and my first attempt) was not very good. Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, SQL Server does not support direct conversion of an expression to true/false.

IMHO, one reason is the 3-valued logic. This has 3 outcomes, not 2, of either column is NULL. The NULL is first in SQL generally, always Server but can be specified last in other RDBMS.

```
 ORDER BY (colX1 = colX2)
```

Using CASE mitigates this and removes ambiguity

```
 ORDER BY
   CASE
       WHEN colX1 = colX2 THEN 1
       WHEN colX1 <> colX2 THEN 2
       ELSE 3 NULL case
   END
```

You have to use CASE as per your update, as well ensuring datatypes match (or at least implicitly convertable) in WHEN clauses.

Answer (score 5):

you can use

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN condition= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
```

Comment: +1 For my example, this is it. See my comment on the question, why I have not taken your answer as the accepted. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can order by the ordinal position of the column, if you want to SEE the data that you're sorting by... for example, if you want to order by the 1st column, just say 'ORDER BY 1'. Here is an example where I add an expression in the select clause.. and then I order by it in the order by clause

```
SELECT colX0, 
(case WHEN colX1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
 FROM tbp_name 
ORDER BY 2
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to put it in your select first

```
SELECT 
  colX0, 
  CASE WHEN colX1 IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS [COMPUTED1]
FROM tbp_name 
ORDER BY COMPUTED1
```

It's something like that anyway off the top of my head.
http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqlcase.php

Comment: No I don't think this is true, see my update and the other posts (and the comment of Rory).